# Query improperly sets rank on user, depending on his total points

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm trying to get all total points per user, sort them in descending order and print their ranks.My query is working almost fine, but it does not set user's rank properly.

```
SET @rank := 0;
SELECT (@rank := @rank + 1) AS rank, u.username, SUM(s.score) AS totalScore
FROM solution AS s
INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = s.author_id
GROUP BY u.username
ORDER BY totalScore DESC
```

**User schema:**

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|         id          |     username     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |       test1      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |       test2      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |       test3      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          8          |       test4      |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

**Solution schema:**

```
|---------------------|------------------|-----------------|
|         id          |     author_id    |      score      |
|---------------------|------------------|-----------------|
|          1          |       1          |       55        |
|---------------------|------------------|-----------------|
|          2          |       2          |       5         |
|---------------------|------------------|-----------------|
|          3          |       3          |       22        |
|---------------------|------------------|-----------------|
|          4          |       8          |       43        |
|---------------------|------------------|-----------------|
|          5          |       8          |       43        |
|---------------------|------------------|-----------------|
```

**The result is:**

```
|---------------------|------------------|-----------------|
|         rank        |     username     |    totalScore   |
|---------------------|------------------|-----------------|
|          4          |       test4      |       86        |
|---------------------|------------------|-----------------|
|          1          |       test1      |       55        |
|---------------------|------------------|-----------------|
|          3          |       test3      |       22        |
|---------------------|------------------|-----------------|
|          2          |       test2      |       5         |
|---------------------|------------------|-----------------|
```

Why does that happen?

**The expected result should be:**

```
|---------------------|------------------|-----------------|
|         rank        |     username     |    totalScore   |
|---------------------|------------------|-----------------|
|          1          |       test4      |       86        |
|---------------------|------------------|-----------------|
|          2          |       test1      |       55        |
|---------------------|------------------|-----------------|
|          3          |       test3      |       22        |
|---------------------|------------------|-----------------|
|          4          |       test2      |       5         |
|---------------------|------------------|-----------------|
```

Comment: With out data for your query we can't test solution and so only tell you what to do,  You have to caluclate first the totalscore and theren use that for the ranking

Comment: What data exactly do you mean? I believe I have provided everything required.

Comment: the tables soolution and users are missing you sum s.score wihich is not available

Comment: Where should I post them?

Comment: ibefore your query or below. But don't forget  the data

Comment: Is the data good enough now?

Comment: Yes see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i said in the comment. You have first sum up the score to rank it.

```
SELECT 
    (@rank:=@rank + 1) rank, username, totalscore
FROM
    (SELECT 
        u.username, SUM(s.score) AS totalScore
    FROM
        solution AS s
    INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = s.author_id
    GROUP BY u.username
    ORDER BY totalScore DESC) t1,
    (SELECT @rank:=0) r1
```

See example the second query is mine

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `username` VARCHAR(5)
);

INSERT INTO users
  (`id`, `username`)
VALUES
  ('1', 'test1'),
  ('2', 'test2'),
  ('3', 'test3'),
  ('8', 'test4');

CREATE TABLE solution (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `author_id` INTEGER,
  `score` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO solution
  (`id`, `author_id`, `score`)
VALUES
  ('1', '1', '55'),
  ('2', '2', '5'),
  ('3', '3', '22'),
  ('4', '8', '43'),
  ('5', '8', '43');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SET @rank := 0;
```

There are no results to be displayed.

---

**Query #2**

```
SELECT (@rank := @rank + 1) AS rank, u.username, SUM(s.score) AS totalScore
FROM solution AS s
INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = s.author_id
GROUP BY u.username
ORDER BY totalScore DESC;

| rank | totalScore | username |
| ---- | ---------- | -------- |
| 4    | 86         | test4    |
| 1    | 55         | test1    |
| 3    | 22         | test3    |
| 2    | 5          | test2    |
```

---

**Query #3**

```
SELECT
(@rank := @rank +1) rank
,username
,totalscore
FROM
(SELECT
u.username,
SUM(s.score) AS totalScore
FROM solution AS s
INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = s.author_id
GROUP BY u.username
ORDER BY totalScore DESC) t1,(SELECT @rank := 0) r1;

| rank | username | totalscore |
| ---- | -------- | ---------- |
| 1    | test4    | 86         |
| 2    | test1    | 55         |
| 3    | test3    | 22         |
| 4    | test2    | 5          |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Answer (score 0):

This will work from MySql:

```
Select username, totalScore, Rank() over (order by totalScore desc) as Rank 
from (
SELECT  u.username, SUM(s.score) AS totalScore
FROM solution AS s
INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = s.author_id
GROUP BY u.username
ORDER BY totalScore DESC
)t
```

Comment: May you write it in MySQL syntax? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I did, it says there is some syntax problem.